# How can i test an interface?

Tags: java, object, testing, interface, junit

I want to do a JUnit test case for an interface, as you know i can't make an object from the interface and i don't want any classes names to show up in that test, i want only to test the interface and only use it's methods in the test.

So, i can't instantiate an object like :

```
Interface obj = new Class();
```

as i don't wont to use any classes methods, and i don't want to instantiate the interface as :

```
Interface var = new Interface{//methods};
```

as i don't want to override the methods in the test.

**UPDATE:**

```
i have an interface and a class which implements it:
public interface inter {
public void method1();
public void method2();
}


public class BlaBla implements inter{
@override
public void method1(){//stuff}
@override
public void method2(){//stuff}
}
```

i want to test BlaBla but deal in my test with it's interface (inter).

Comment: What are you planning to test exactly? There shouldn't be much code in an interface since the methods are abstract

Comment: What is the goal of testing an interface as by definition, there is no code to test, only signatures?

Comment: @Guillaume when you run a method from an interface what happened ?? that's the same concept i wanna follow. the methods that will be tested is the methods that in the class, but i don't want to create a class instance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An `interface` is a contract. It has no logic to test.

You can use a mocking framework like [`Mockito`](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to create an instance of the `interface` without having to manually stub the methods. But it will just stub them in the background.

You have to ask yourself *what* you want to test? Given that the `interface` methods have **no** implementation there is **no** code *to test*.

Say I have an `interface` like so

```
public interface DoesStuff {
    void doStuff();
}
```

What is there to test? The only thing I have said is that I want a class that `implements DoesStuff` to `doStuff`.

Comment: for sure, there is a class that implements that interface and the methods overridden in it. but in the test i don't want to make object from that class as i don't wont to deal with the class from the test.

Comment: If you want to use the `interface` _in_ your test then that is a different question. Are you testing another `class` that depends on this interface?

Comment: +1 for mockito! It's the best (imho) mocking library in existence.

Comment: yes, you got the point. but i want to deal with the interface not the class

Comment: In that case look at my link for Mockito - this is exactly what you want. You can even make the mocked interface do things with fluent command such as `when(myIntefaceInstance.getName()).thenReturn("Bob")`.

Answer (score 7):

The *only* way to test an interface is to create a concrete class that implements it, instantiate it and test that class. You can't test an interface directly, because as you know, it can't be instantiated, leaving nothing to be tested. This should be obvious: an interface is just a collection of method signatures, with no method bodies - hence there is no behavior to be tested.

Comment: for sure, there is a class that implements that interface and the methods overridden in it. but in the test i don't want to make object from that class as i don't wont to deal with the class from the test.

Comment: "The only way to test an interface is to create a concrete class" <-- uh NO! What about mocking libraries?

Comment: @fge umm, no. And what do you think the mocking library does? create a concrete class, of course! you're missing the point, an interface is non-testable in and of itself.

Comment: That is not always true.  I am trying to test a http method in spring, it gets its data from a database repository using hibernate. I want to use a mock interface to simulate the data return from the database, but since the database query is returning an aggregate method, hibernate requires you to use an interface with methods such as getCount etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no functionality to test in an interface (because it cannot be instantiated; it has no method implementations). So there is nothing JUnit can do with it.

Comment: there is a class implements that interface but i don't want to make my test on the class or to make an instance from it.

Comment: Then the best you can do is to 'mock' that class (which implements the interface) using JMock or some similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an **abstract base class for unit tests**. For specific classes that implement the interface a unit test would simply extend the abstract base class.

The abstract base class could test things that should hold, like `close` after `open` or other things.