# How to test a java interface?

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface, junit, instance

I have an interface and a class that implements that interface and overrides it's methods:

```
public interface Intr {
public int method1();
public int method2();
}


public class example implements Intr{
@override
public int method1()
{
//stmts
}
@override
public int method2(){
//stmts
}
}
```

i want to create a JUnit test to test that interface **without implementing the class on my test**, i used a code like :

```
public class TIntr {

    private Intr interface;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public Object testMethod1() {
        try{
        int result = interface.method1();
        assertEquals(something, result);
        }catch(Exception e){
        fail("Test Failed!!");
        }


        @Test
    public Object testMethod1() {
        try{
        int result = interface.method2();
        assertEquals(something, result);
        }catch(Exception e){
        fail("Test Failed!!");
        }
}
```

but the test always fails as the execution of the methods always generate null values as i didn't create instance from the class, only a variable from the type interface.

Comment: Seriously, why are you wasting our time: You JUST POSTED THIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108142/how-can-i-test-an-interface

Comment: The test fails? Are you sure? It shouldn't even compile considerung the forbidden use of the keyword `interface`.

Comment: You don't really "test an interface". You test its implementations. If you want to test interactions with this interface you need a mocking library like Mockito.

Comment: @jlordo you say to me you didn't notice that this an example?

Comment: @JohnB you didn't figure that i wrote a code now and want to discuss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/). `EasyMock` creates a mock object based on the interface. The mock object implements all the methods of the interface and for those methods you specify (e.g. with expect), it "replays" the specified behaviour when they are called.

It should be something like:

```
Intr mockedDependency = createMock(Intr.class);
expect(mockedDependency.method1()).andReturn(100);
```

Although, I don't see why are you testing an interface.

Comment: thanks, it worked, and testing the interface is a work stuff that i hate to do :D